# Change RadTimePicker value programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, browser

I'm having trouble in changing RadTimePicker value programmatically from WebBrowser control (it is an automated tool for operation with some website)

[image: datetimepicker]

I'm using Firebug add-on for Firefox to find the right control to change its value. But when I locate date textbox and change its value arg in the app - nothing happens.

Could you please point me on the right way how can I change date in RadDatPicker?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to set a value in the picker, you should be using its SetSelectedDate() method to assign a date to it.

```
var datePicker = $find("<%= RadDatePicker1.ClientID %>");            
datePicker.set_selectedDate(new Date());
```

This should solve it:

```
window.frames[0].$find('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RadDatePicker1').set_selectedDate(new Date('2020/10/12'))
```

Comment: Does it mean that I can replace your "<%= RadDatePicker1.ClientID %>" with the datePicker's ID and then set it to new date? Or what percent symbol stands for? I'm not familiar with JS, sorry.

Comment: @JeffreyRasmussen, Yes, replace 'RadDatePicker1' with the name of your control, and change 'datePicker.set_selectedDate(new Date());' to be the date you want to use! :)  Don't forget to vote up and mark my answer as correct :)

Comment: OK ;) One more question to you. When I locate calendar control using Firebug, it points me on the following elements: div, input (calendarSD), input (calendatAD) (in hierarchy order). Which one is the actual datePicker's ID?

Comment: Probably I found it: <input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RadDatePicker1" class="rdfd_" type="text" title="" value="2012-06-13" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$RadDatePicker1" style="visibility:hidden;display:block;float:right;margin:0 0 -1px -1px;width:1px;height:1px;overflow:hidden;border:0;padding:0;">

Comment: so should I use ID or Name attribute value? I'm sorry for that noob questions.

Comment: Still trying to get it solved.. :) I could find element using frames[i].document.getElementById('id here'). So radDatePicker element is in a frame. How can I use $find method in the frame? Simply calling $find returns null... Vijay, please help ;)

Comment: Is this page online?  If it is give me the URL and I'll give you steps to replicate... Once you find the control (which you said you have already done) then just run datePicker.set_selectedDate(new Date()); on it.  But as I said, show me the page and I'll give you exact steps to replicate!

Comment: so something like frames[i].document.getElementById('id here').set_selectedDate(new Date()); would do it...

Comment: @JeffreyRasmussen How about a URL so that I can check it out?  If it's on your local machine then just open up your ports, publish your website publicly and give me your public IP so I can access it on your machine... Going to sleep now, will check on here at 10:00 GMT for a response :)